# to enabled sqlite , what to include in php.in

Tags: sqlite, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sqlite is not working.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564249/sqlite-is-not-working)

i am tried hard to connect sqlite database using php. after lot of search, i found to include the below lines in php.ini. i am not sure where to include.

**extension=php_pdo.dll 
 extension=php_sqlite.dll** 
i could't find even a word called sqlite in php.ini. can any give the sample php.ini with sqlite enable

Comment: Just look for other lines like that and put it at the end. Make sure you have the DLL files though. Then restart apache

Comment: [four](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513850/how-to-connect-a-sqlite-database-using-php) [in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552467/problem-connecting-to-a-sqlite-database-using-php) [a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564249/sqlite-is-not-working) [row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564567/to-enabled-sqlite-what-to-include-in-php-in)

Answer (score 0):

If your connect to sqlite from pdo try (maybe) set in php.ini odbc.allow_persistent = On
When i install centos 5 to my server and check all repositories i don't find php-sqlite module and developers compile php without sqlite. I use PDO php function for sqlite:
$x = new PDO("sqlite:......");
And i thing your can try odbc.allow_persistent = On